# What's my corn snakes gender pic provided

Tags: snakes

Hey just wondering what gender my snake can anyone tell by the pic please reply asap[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is most likely a female. A better photo would increase the accuracy of the prediction, but it appears that her tail narrows immediately after the cloaca, which indicates a lack of hemipenes, thus female.